# Making a fat jar for just one class in my eclispe project

Tags: java, maven

I am creating fat jar for my maven project and my project has many claases dependency. Actually, it is an apache beam project which I always upload to google data flow.

I am writing some codes and everytime I want to debug and test the code I shoud uplaod a 200MB fat jar to the server, Can I just make my fat jar for just one classes in my project?

Comment: You can build a normal jar with just your classes. The real question here is however, if you could use that on your runtime environment.

Comment: You can do it, but you should upload the dependencies before and then use -cp option to point to the dependencies while running